# How to store a full Firestore query path?

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

After doing a query to Firestore i'm attempting to store the Firestore path so that i can acces it later.

This way i can do a Firestore query and attach a listener. On the second query i can access that stored path to detach the old listener and attach a new one.

When initializing a app a query is executed.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let path = Firestore.firestore().collection("all_users").document(uid).collection("usercollection").whereField("datefilter", isGreaterThan: self.currentDate)
        newSearch(firebasePath: path)
```

However, storing the path is necessary as the query can change in unpredictable ways. Below is a function that changes the query depending on user input.

```
func filterQuery(filterText:string) {
        let path = Firestore.firestore().collection("all_users").document(uid).collection(filterText).whereField("datefilter", isGreaterThan: self.currentDate)
        newSearch(firebasePath: path)
```

A query is made and a listener is attached on that specific query. This way i can grab the data and listen when something is modified to that specific query.

```
func newSearch(firebasePath: Query) {
        
        //REMOVE OLD LISTENER IF IT EXISTS OR IF QUERY IS THE SAME ---> ADD NEW ONE AT THE END OF FUNCTION
        if self.storedFirebasePath != nil {
            if self.storedFirebasePath != firebasePath {
                 let listener = 
                 self.storedFirebasePath.addSnapshotListener { snapshot, error in
                 }
                 listener.remove()
            }
        }

        let queryRef = firebasePath
        queryRef.getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
    
                if err == nil && querySnapshot != nil {
                    if querySnapshot!.documents.count > 0 {
                        self.mapIsEmpty = false
                        for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                            
                            let data = document.data()
                            //MANAGING DATA....
                         }
                     
                     } else {
                        
                        print("NO DATA")
                     }
                 }               
             }
        }
        //STORE FIRESTORE PATH
        self.storedFirebasePath = queryRef

        //ATTACH LISTENER
        self.realTimeUpdates(firebasePath: firebasePath)
    }
}
```

With code below i get "Currently i get the Error = 'init()' is unavailable: FIRQuery cannot be created directly"

```
var storedFirebasePath = Query()
```

Maybe the parameters used to create the query can be stored to recreate the path. Or is there a better practice to do what i'm attempting

Comment: What is `var storedFirebasePath = Query()` supposed to do? If you just want to initialize `storedFirebasePath`, then you should probably initialize it to `nil`.

Comment: I want to be able to store the path "Firestore.firestore().collection("All_users") as a variable. This way i could access that specific path later if needed. Lets say i do a Firestore query and i add a snapshotlistener to it. Later i want to query for something new and remove the old snapshotlistener by accessing the stored Firestore path.

Comment: Doesn't your `self.storedFirebasePath = queryRef` already store that "path"?

Comment: Unfortunately i get the Error = 'init()' is unavailable: FIRQuery cannot be created directly. Not sure what this means or how to handle it.

Comment: It's really not clear what you're attempting to do. This `var storedFirebasePath = Query()` is not a query so.. what's that in reference to? Also, what is the point of storing a path to a known static top level collection? e.g. your users collection will always be `self.db.collection("users")`. There's really no need to store a path to that since it's a static path. Can you clarify what your asking and perhaps we can come up with a solution. Oh - you cannot 'compare queries' in Firebase (you could do that in code) but that needs clarification as well.

Comment: I rephrased my question explanation. Hopefully this way it makes it more clear what it is that i'm attempting to do.

Comment: The problem is the question and what you're attempting to do don't match so it's confusing. The question states -*store a path*- where a path would be */users/uid/*. It seems like you're trying to store the actual query including the filtering portion, so it's not a *path*, it's the query itself. You could probably encapsulate that into some kind of *Data* object but I don't think the effort would be worth it, and I've never seen a need for it. So maybe an explanation of *why* you need to do this would help us - what's the use  case? Why can't you build the query when the user provides input?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think what you're trying to do is possible. You can however store a document reference. But even with a document reference you can't detach listeners with it.

Comment: Was hoping Something similar to this would be possible. This however requires that the Firestore path can be saved.     let listener = self.storedFirebasePath.addSnapshotListener { snapshot, error in
}
listener.remove()

Comment: Edited the question explanation in order to make it clear.